# Pass Ctrl-Q through to a webpage in Firefox

Tags: firefox

Running `chrome` in Windows 10 I could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to quote a block of text when writing a question / answer on the Stackexchange sites.

Now I'm running `Mozilla Firefox 50.1.0` on Manjaro, pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> gives me a popup:

> This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.

How do I pass <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> through to a webpage in Firefox? (Or, alternatively, how do I quote a block of text without pressing those keys?)

[Keybinder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/keybinder/)    allows me to disable the sequence, or even to change it, but having    tried both: the key combination is *not* passed through to the webpage    being viewed.

Comment: I voted to keep this question open but on consideration, I think it would be more appropriate for [su]. Answers to this question would be more specific to Firefox (regardless of platform) rather than Unix or Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [page that describes the shortcuts](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Basic-Browsing/Keyboard-shortcuts-Perform-common-Firefox-tasks-quickly/ta-p/3866?as=u&redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Keyboard+shortcuts&utm_source=inproduct) (Help > Keyboard shortcuts) refers the reader to an [extension that allows configuration of the keys](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/).

On my Windows platform Ctrl+Q has no effect, and as I don't run Firefox on my Linux systems I can't confirm this myself.